# How to get the progress of the current animation sequence in TimelineMax

Tags: javascript, animation, gsap

I am using timelinemax to perform a series of tweens as follows:

```
this.backgroundColorTimeline = new TimelineMax({
    repeat: -1,
    yoyo: true,
    onUpdate:this.updateTimeline,
});

palette.bg.forEach((paletteColor) => {
    this.backgroundColorTimeline.add(TweenMax.to(this.bg, settings.colorAnimTime, {
        easel: { tint: paletteColor },
    }));
});
```

While each TweenMax instance is running, I want to be able to get its progress. So if my timeline has 10 tweenmax animations, I want to get each animation's progress (as a scale from 0 to 1) on update.

I see that timelinemax has a `progress` event, but that wouldn't divide the time up by each animation.

How do I get just the current animation's progress?

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `onUpdate` callback to track each instance's progress:

**ES5 Way**

```
function getProgress () {
    var currProgress = this.progress();
}
palette.bg.forEach((paletteColor) => {
    this.backgroundColorTimeline.add(TweenMax.to(this.bg, settings.colorAnimTime,{
        easel: { tint: paletteColor },
        onUpdate: getProgress
    }));
});
```

---

**ES6+ Way**

```
const getProgress = t {
    const currProgress = t.progress();
}
palette.bg.forEach((paletteColor) => {
    this.backgroundColorTimeline.add(TweenMax.to(this.bg, settings.colorAnimTime,{
        easel: { tint: paletteColor },
        onUpdate: getProgress, onUpdateParams: ["{self}"]
    }));
});
```